# Random numbers in linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, random, lazy-sequences

Is it true that random data inside a lazy statement might get evaluated differently at runtime? With the following code, I see "wow" printed to the console many times. However, if I force the result of the query (i.e. call `ToList()` on `xs` and `ys`), things seem to work fine.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var generator = new Random();
        var xs = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 20000)
                 select generator.Next();

        var ys = from y in Enumerable.Range(0, 5000)
                 select generator.Next();

        foreach (var x in xs)
        {
            var q1 = from y in ys where y > x select y;
            var q2 = from y in ys where y > x select y;

            if (!q1.SequenceEqual(q2))
                Console.WriteLine("wow!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

I suspect that this has to do with the fact that linq queries are "lazy". Is this accurate?

Comment: the "deferred execution" of LINQ queries is one of the most common misunderstood features. A query is always executed when the query variable is iterated over, not when the query variable is created.

Comment: I really want to come up with an answer that "fixes" this by using a `new Random` for each iteration of `ys`, but I can't figure out how to do it without making it obvious :(

Comment: @Rawling `from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 20000) let rnd = new Random() select rnd.Next();
`

Comment: @xanatos Nah, that doesn't seem to do it - you get a `new Random` for each `y` rather than each `ys`, and I think that slows it down enough that it breaks.

Comment: @Rawling You are right: `(from useless in new int[1] let rnd = new Random() from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 20000) select rnd.Next()).ToArray();`

Comment: @xanatos Nice - that gives similar results to my solution, which was to put it in an iterator method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it true that random data inside a lazy statement might get evaluated differently at runtime?*

What is true is that, as you have written:

> *I suspect that this has to do with the fact that linq queries are "lazy". Is this accurate?*

An important additional thing is that they aren't "materialized"/"cached" after execution, so every time you execute them, they are regenerated.

This line

```
if (!q1.SequenceEqual(q2))
    Console.WriteLine("wow!");
```

will cause the evaluation of the `q1` and `q2` enumerables, that each will cause the enumeration of `ys`. So `ys` will be "generated" twice for each cycle of the `foreach` cycle.

So, considering that the `foreach` cycle will do 20000 "cyles", ys will be "generated" 40000 times.

The `Random.Next()` will be executed 20000 + (20000 * 2 * 5000) times, where

```
20000: the xs sequence, used only once by the foreach cycle:
20000 * 2 * 5000: 20000 cycles in which the ys sequence is used twice
```

Note what would have happened if:

```
var xs = (from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 20000)
         select generator.Next()).ToArray();

var ys = (from y in Enumerable.Range(0, 5000)
         select generator.Next()).ToArray();
```

Here we are "materializing" the enumerables in an array (in two arrays to be precise). The `Random.Next()` will be called a grandtotal of `20000 + 5000` times, and it will be done directly in these two lines. The enumeration of `xs` and `ys` won't cause the generation of new random numbers.

Comment: Thank you -- that is an important thing to keep in mind.

Comment: @rookie I've updated the response adding another piece.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is more or less what I noticed when calling `ToList()` on the queries before entering the `foreach` loop.